# How to get information of signed in user by Outlook rest api

Tags: outlook-restapi

After a user signed in a web app that uses outlook api with microsoft account, how do we get the profile information of that user, e.g. email address, display name or event the profile photo? A user might have multiple microsoft accounts and need to know which accout he/she is signing in. I didn't find anything related in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about the user in the ID token that comes back as part of the signin process. Here's a good article on ID token when using the Azure v1 auth: http://andrewconnell.com/blog/azure-ad-oauth2-openid-connect. Here's the docs for v2: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc/.

For the photo, you want to look at the User Photo API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/photo-rest-operations

Comment: Thanks! It works fine extracting user profile (display name, email etc.) from id token. But the photo api seems broken. I played with that api in oauth sandbox (https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/) but always got "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'userphotos'."
    }

even the account I used has valid profile photo.

Comment: It's not `/userphoto`. Try `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value`, which is one of the requests in the drop down on that site.

Comment: This is the url I was looking for! Thank you Jason. I shouldn't have relied on the sandbox.

Comment: You should also include "nonce" which is just a random GUID which can be generated here >  https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx. Without it, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Does this work for consecutive calls with the same GUID ? It worked for the first time but on the next calls, it won't hit the redirect URI. The code is spitted on the browser url but never hits redirect url.

Comment: You shouldn't reuse a nonce value, so my guess is that the server is detecting that and not issuing a token.